# Changing the id value of a cloned html element

Tags: jquery, html

i don't know why the id of my cloned element doesn't change. here's the code i'm working on.

```
 c.children('#response1').attr('id','response'+ (++inputs) );
```

[JSFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/9UZcV/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input element you are trying to select is NOT a direct child of the row tag. The `children()` function only selects direct children. You can use the `find()` function to get a non-direct descendant.

You can look at this updated fiddle that will show you the id when you click on the input textbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/9UZcV/3/

By the way, you have another error in your code. If you add 3 rows (or more) and then remove a row that is not the last row, and then add another row, you will get duplicate IDs. The reason is that you decrement the `inputs` counter when you remove a row, even if it is not the last row. E.g.:

Add two rows.

```
response1
response2 
response3
```

Now delete the second row.

```
response1
response3
```

Add another row

```
response1
response3
response3  (this is the new one. duplicate id)
```

The solution is to either not decrement `inputs` (unless it is the last row, but this is optional). If you definitely need to have sequentially numbered items, then you'll have to simply re-number them whenever an input is removed from any position except the end.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of children(), you need to use find().
Children only works for the direct children, not for children's children.